# Restrict a picklist field value if a different field on same object = false

Tags: picklist, validation, validation-rule

I hope this is easy, but I'm just having a brain fart. I need to make one of the status values in a picklist field status to be disabled unless a different field on same object = false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple validation rule, if your preference is to surface an error. (You've tagged your question `validation-rule`). Something like

```
ISPICKVAL(My_picklist__c, 'RESTRICTED_VALUE') && NOT(Other_field__c)
```

This assumes that `Other_field__c` is a checkbox field.

Note, however, that this doesn't disable the entry in the picklist *user interface*: it simply prevents a record from being saved with this combination of data points.

Alternately, you can make a checkbox field the [controlling field](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_defining_field_dependencies.htm&type=5) of your picklist. This would allow you to determine which picklist choices show up at all based on the checkbox's selection state.

Comment: Yes this looks awesome thank you, I only want the one picklist value to be restricted on save IF the other (checkbox) field is false

Comment: New question. How would I make the vice-versa of this? I have the value I want restricted if the other field referenced is false. Now for the other field in the picklist I want restricted if the other field referenced is true. Basically how do you have multiple fields into that ISPICKVAL expression? Do I need to make multiple validation rules or can this be done inside of one?

Comment: Either way. You may want a second validation rule to surface a different error message, or you can wrap multiple expressions like this in the OR() function.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I wound up doing 5 ISPICKVAL’s inside () and the NOT(other_field__c = true), what I needed was one VR for when the other_field__c was true and one for when it was false. Thanks again!

Comment: Sure thing. If you develop a lot of complexity here you may want to revisit picklist dependency and see if it meets your needs for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

### You have to setup [Field Dependency](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_defining_field_dependencies.htm&type=5):

> 1. From the management settings for the object you want to add a field
>      to, go to Fields.
>      Custom task and event fields are accessible from the object management settings for Activities.
> 2. Click **Field Dependencies**.
> 3. Click **New**.
> 4. Choose a controlling field and dependent field.
>
>    - **Note** *Some picklist and checkbox fields may not be available as    controlling fields.*
> 5. Click Continue.
> 6. Use the [field dependency matrix](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_using_the_field_dependency_matrix.htm&type=5) to specify the dependent picklist
>      values that are available when a user selects each controlling field
>      value.
> 7. Optionally, click Preview to test your selections. If your
>      organization uses record types, choose a record type to test how it
>      affects your controlling and dependent picklist values. The record
>      type controls what values are available in the controlling field.
>      The record type and the controlling field together determine what
>      values are available in the dependent picklist. For example, a
>      dependent value is only available if it is available in the selected
>      record type and the selected controlling value.
> 8. Click Save.
>
>    - **Note** *The Filter by Record Type option doesn’t appear in the Preview window for activity custom fields.*

Comment: Please don't write a link-only answer. Links can go bad, and the information lost. See [answer] for guidelines on writing a good answer.